# Force.com Canvas App - rendering fails after Winter '16 update in sandbox

Tags: canvas, salesforce, integration

I have been working on a Force.com Canvas App integration between Salesforce and ADF. The Canvas App is OAuth and viewed within a Community on a Visualforce Page. Before Winter 16 upgrade, everything was working fine. Winter '16 was released for the sandbox over the weekend and now all Canvas Apps fail to render regardless of the Canvas App URL.

The error is "Unable to retrieve signed request from the server. Please try your request later."

In the DevTools console in Chrome, I see a network request to:

https://example.force.com/services/data/v35.0/platformconnect/signedrequest?canvas=Desktop_Canvas_App

In an org that is still on Summer '15, the Canvas App request is

https://example.force.com/services/data/v34.0/platformconnect/signedrequest?canvas=Desktop_Canvas_App

If I view the same page outside of the Community as a System Administrator user, the canvas app does load, but the communication between the Visualforce page and the Canvas App URL fails.

I have added all possible permissions to the Canvas App as well as revoked the Canvas App access and re-initialized the OAuth access to the app, but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the Known Issue - [Force.com Canvas App Issue after Winter '16 Upgrade](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000001AHnAAM)

> **Summery**
>      In Winter' 16, sandboxes, there is a Canvas session issue in all the browsers when accessing via community.

---

Is the Org that defines your connected app still on Summer '15? If so, it won't understand the v35.0 API calls from a Winter '16 org.

Can you modify the signedrequest call to use /v34.0/ rather than /v35.0/ until the org that defines the connected app is also on Winter '16?

Comment: I am having the same problem and salesforce is initiating the request. so we do not have any control on the version.